# Google+ signIn using Javascript redirects to blank page

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I am trying to implement google SignIn in my HTML Mobile app using web-views.

I have designed a page with the help of https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow

When I click signin button the Page redirects to signin dialogue. After successful login am seeing a blank white screen.

What might be the problem ? Is it due to the web-view ?

Any work around please ?

Comment: This is a native app with an embedded webview, is that correct? If so, you should be using the native sign-in flow rather than the web-based sign-in flow for this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: Its a Hybrid App. I am loading html pages inside Android-WebView. I have sign-flow implemented on HTML pages.

Comment: Yeah, so on the HTML pages, you should invoke a JavaScript function that you bind in your WebView to invoke the native sign-in flow.

Comment: The reason you should use the native sign-in flow in this case is that the native flow can leverage the credentials already provisioned on the device whereas the web-based flow cannot. Furthermore, in a web view, the user will have no way of verifying in the URL bar that the authority of the login page is "https://accounts.google.com/", so they will have no way of being confident that they are entering their credentials into Google as opposed to a page that simply looks like Google.